# Does chrome support audio codec G722,G723,G729?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc, html5-audio, sipjs

Recently, when using sip.js to write a webrtc project, we cannot use the G722,G723 or G729 to make calls.Does Chrome support these voice codes？

I think G722 is workable. How about the others?

Answer (score 0):

According to my testing, Chromium-based browsers support G.711 (µ-law and A-law), G.722, ISAC and Opus.